# how to 1.download image 2. resize to avatar 3. cache it 4. add to list item 5.fetch image from cache only

Tags: android, image, list, caching, resize

I have a list of push messages(txt) and a fixed image(the size of avatar).
now i've added in the server the option to upload a photo. the server will host only the latest uploaded photo. I like to:
1. download the image on receive new push notification
2. resize it to avatar size
3. update the list item avatar image
4. cache the image for future refference

note, I can't take the corresponding avatar from the server after a new image has been uploaded because it will not be served anymore,only the last to upload ,so a caching mechanizm is needed.

example:
1. push(text) is shot from server - android request the image(lets say no.1)
2. new push msg(2) is shot - new image is served from the server(overrides the img1)
3. android list must show the avatars of image1 and image2 (image1 from cache)
and so on

any incites will be happily accepted :)

Thanx!

Comment: if you are using list http://negativeprobability.blogspot.in/2011/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-listview.html

Comment: What a question title !!

Comment: The only issue with the given example is that I use only 1 url everytime. the server will change the image from time to time,and will serve the image to the same url, and i need to keep the images that was sent previously as avatars. the Cache key currently is url and this implementation cannot be used. it will override the cache due to "same key" issue.same url = same cache key = override :)